# Hide menu d3js satellite node when the mouse is not over

Tags: menu

D3js have a tree in which to position myself above each node (mouseover) satellite menu. So far everything ok, the problem is that can not get out of the node longer visibible node, for example, standing on the white area of the screen. Instead, I do what I do is that when you go to any other element of the html (mouseover) that menu is hidden.

Comment: [checkmark]: http://testenvironment.es/menusatelite.png

Comment: Alguien que me pueda ayudar con éste tema?.